# I have a modulating gas water heater, I also have a small solar water heater system. Can I feed the gas boiler with the output from the Solar system

Tags: water-heater

I am working on the theory that any hot water that is available from the solar system will pre-heat the water going into the Gas Boiler, but the elctronics and the modulating valve in the gas boiler will control the final output of the system. Obviousley it cannot cool the water, if the output from the solar system is hotter than what the temperature is higher than the setting on the gas boiler, but I can live with that. What are your thoughts?

Comment: That is the usual way, only use the gas to keep the water hot when the solar does not.

Comment: Will need to be careful if water temperature is above 120 degrees if young children/old people use it if no anti-scalding valves used at the faucets.

Comment: Do you directly consume the water going the the solar system, or does it have a coolant fluid (like your car's radiator fluid) that then goes through a heat exchanger to heat the actual house potable water supply?

Comment: Sanity check: are you talking about using solar to heat/preheat the water heater, or a forced-hot-water heating system?

Answer (score 1):

Check your gas boiler specs, to make sure the solar will supply enough pressure and flow.

Usually solar heaters have low flow and low pressure which will not work well for the gas heater.

Comment: Also, what happens in winter? Is the solar water heater drained, if it gets cold in your area?

Comment: In _most_ places, @DrMoishePippik, the sun also shines in the winter...

Comment: @FreeMan shining is not the same as producing sufficient heat to keep pipes from freezing -- specially at **night** time.